# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null reading local file

Tags: android-image

A quick summary of my problem: I am trying to read a local image file.  If I include the file in my assets directory and treat it as an asset everything works fine.  However, if I try to read it from the external sd card, BitmapFactory.decode stream returns null.
I've had the same results with both .jpeg and .png files.

This is how I obtain an InputStream from the asset file:

```
InputStream isa = context.getAssets().open("Boulder.jpg");
```

This is how I obtain an InputStream from the asset file:

```
File f = new File( "/mnt/extSdCard/Maps/Colorado/Boulder.jpg" );
InputStream isf = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( f.toString() ) );
```

In either case the InputStream is passed to this code: (If this code looks familiar, it was borrowed from an internet example)

```
this.decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, false);

tmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;   
Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, tmpOptions);
setSceneSize(tmpOptions.outWidth, tmpOptions.outHeight);

tmpOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
tmpOptions.inSampleSize = (1<<downShift);
sampleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, tmpOptions);
```

Again, using the asset file derived InputStream, everything works fine.  Conversely, with the sdCard file, outWidth and outHeight are both -1 after the first call and sampleBitmap is null after the second.

I'm really wrapped around the axle on with this problem and have spent a lot of time browsing this forum and experimenting with suggested solutions all to no avail. I also wrote some test code which opened both versions of the file, creating InputStreams as shown above, then read the contents of each stream and compared each byte and found them to be identical.

I've tried the code on different devices with the same results.  I'm currently testing on a Galaxy Note II (Android 4.1.1) with the following version info in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

I need the ability to dynamically add files to the system so including everything as an asset is not an option.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use

```
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), tmpOptions);
```

rather than

File f = new File( "/mnt/extSdCard/Maps/Colorado/Boulder.jpg" );
InputStream isf = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( f.toString() ) );
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, tmpOptions)